# R format NaN funciton

Tags: r, formatting, format, latex

I'm trying to find a format function which will suppress `NaN` output in R. I want to pass in a vector of double and have the `NaN` values return as empty and not as `NaN`. I'm trying for format output for a Latex table. This should be simple right? Is there such a function?

Here is what I get now:

```
> x <- c(seq(1,2,0.2), NaN)
> as.character(x)
> [1] "1"   "1.2" "1.4" "1.6" "1.8" "2"  "NaN"
```

This is what I want to get:

```
> x <- c(seq(1,2,0.2), NaN)
> formatting.function(x)
> [1] "1"   "1.2" "1.4" "1.6" "1.8" "2"  ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
R> x <- c(seq(1,2,0.2), NaN)
R> zx <- as.character(x)
R> zx
[1] "1"   "1.2" "1.4" "1.6" "1.8" "2"   "NaN"
```

So now we define a new function `mattFun()`:

```
R> mattFun <- function(x) gsub("NaN", "", as.character(x))
```

and use it:

```
R> zy <- mattFun(x)
R> zy
[1] "1"   "1.2" "1.4" "1.6" "1.8" "2"   ""   
R>
```

In all seriousness, you are simply looking for a simple pattern replacement which is what 
regular expressions do. `gsub()` is one of several functions offering that.  Try to read up on regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "NaN" by "":

```
x <- c(seq(1,2,0.2), NaN)
fofu <- function(x){
   cx <- as.character(x)
   cx[cx=="NaN"] <- ""
   cx
   }
fofu(x)
#[1] "1"   "1.2" "1.4" "1.6" "1.8" "2"   ""
```

#### (edit)

Or using implicit conversion to make it shorter:

```
fofu2 <- function(x)  "[<-"(x, is.nan(x), "")
# or ... replace(x, is.nan(x), "")
```

This is about two times faster than the gsub based solution (using `microbenchmark` and `x` as defined above) - although of course, what matters most of the time, is convenience rather than computing time.